# Mercurial error on commit: "abort: phases.new-commit: not a valid phase name ('')"

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm getting the following error when attempting to commit to a Hg repository:

```
Z:\wormcard_maker>hg commit -m "asdf"
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: phases.new-commit: not a valid phase name ('')
```

This happens over multiple different repositories and has survived re-cloning the repository and reinstalling Mercurial. I can commit to the repository fine from a different computer (running Linux).

I'm running Hg 4.8 as distributed with TortoiseHg 4.8 on Windows 7.

Comment: Well that's heartening; I was worried it was a hardware problem because I couldn't find any information about it on the internet. Someone else having the same problem doesn't prove it isn't hardware, I guess, but it makes it less likely.

Comment: What does the relevant config file(s) say about `[phases] new-commit = <HERE>`? Valid entries are draft, public and secret.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In TortoiseHg just set the "File - Settings - Commit - New Commit Phase" option.

Comment: Thanks; this fixed it. Not familiar enough with Hg to know what that setting actually does; seems like a documentation issue I should maybe chase up.

Comment: @JamesPicone `hg phase --help`

Answer (score 0):

I tried using [the THG setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53591627/3195477) but it didn't work; just kept producing the same error. 
(While doing this I noticed that the THG dropdown for the phase choices had a bunch of blank lines in it; so I think THG was confused.)

Instead I manually edited my HGRC file and made sure it contained:

```
[phases]
new-commit = secret
```

which worked.

You could obviously use `draft`, etc. in place of `secret`.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the other answers worked for me - even though I had `new-commit = secret` in the HGRC it still produced the error.

The workaround I found was to do this:

```
hg ci -m "message" --config phases.new-commit=secret
```

which did work, apparently by overriding whatever invalid phase name hg was trying to use. Even though I don't know why.

I assume this would work with other comments, not just `ci` (aka `commit`).